# Android - ContentProvider - How to use setReadPermission() and setWritePermission()?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I'm reading the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#setReadPermission(java.lang.String) and it says `Change the permission required to read data from the content provider. This is normally set for you from its manifest information when the provider is first created.`

But I'm unable to change permission on a new one. I tried to call this in constructor and in `onCreate()`, but nothing was changed. When I run command from adb to update the data, I receive error `Permission Denial: opening provider com.test.MyContentProvider from (null) (pid=5641, uid=2000) requires OLD.PERMISSION`

How to solve that? Thanks

UPD with my code:

```
<permission android:name="test.test.TEST" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="test.test.TEST" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.test.MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </provider>
```

MyContentProvider.java:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public MyContentProvider() {
        setReadPermission("test.test.TEST");
        setWritePermission("test.test.TEST");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        setReadPermission("test.test.TEST");
        setWritePermission("test.test.TEST");
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

So when I try to call from ADB the following command it successfully finishes (but shouldn't because it was updated to the permission with signature protection level)

```
content insert --uri content://com.test/x --bind column_name:s:new_value
```

And vise versa if I setup read&write permissions in manifest to the signature permission and after reset it to a normal permission, I get error that says that I miss required permission (the old one)

Comment: You should probably go ahead and post your actual code. I'd never tried this before, but it works as expected for me.

Comment: @MikeM. Updated with my code

Comment: @MikeM.suggest something please?